# reCaptcha Enterprise Uncaught Error: [object Map Iterator] is not an iterable or ArrayLike

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

I use reCaptcha Enterprise and sometimes I get Uncaught Error: [object Map Iterator] is not an iterable or ArrayLike:

```
Uncaught Error: [object Map Iterator] is not an iterable or ArrayLike
    at Array.<anonymous> (recaptcha__pl.js:54:342)
    at n1.<anonymous> (recaptcha__pl.js:207:290)
    at Qy (recaptcha__pl.js:596:338)
    at L (recaptcha__pl.js:229:168)
```

I already tried multiple recaptcha site keys and different placements of reCaptcha script, but there is still an error.

Currently, I use next code in body tag:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

And my callback looks like this:

```
recaptcha = grecaptcha.enterprise.render('recaptcha', {
                'sitekey': '${sitekey}'
            });
```

Do you know how to fix it?

EDIT:

When the error occurred, recaptcha shows this error:
[image]

EDIT2:

It seems to me that the error occurs after refreshing the page with reCaptcha several times, but I'm not 100% sure, because sometimes it looks like random error

EDIT3:

Part of reCaptcha code with error from debug:
[image]

Comment: Does `'${sitekey}'` contain the actual API key in your actual code or did you mean `\`${sitekey}\`` or `sitekey` instead?

Comment: @SebastianSimon ${sitekey} is a variable in JSP that contains reCaptcha client key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google "reCaptcha" sometimes doesn't get displayed/rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776929/google-recaptcha-sometimes-doesnt-get-displayed-rendered)

Comment: @angel.bonev unfortunately, I just tried to render reCaptcha when register view appears, but still same error

Comment: @TarasMelon try without async

Comment: @angel.bonev already tried, still same problem